# Tikz doesn't show anything

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying the `tikz` package for the first time and I have this code:

```
\usepackage{tikz}

fgfdhghgd

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0) -- (0,1) -- (1,1);
\end{tikzpicture}

ksgkgskjs
```

But it just shows a few space lines like this:

```
fgfdhghgd


ksgkgskjs
```

I don't know what could be the problem

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. Please provide a compilable version of your document, not just fragments

Comment: Nothing wrong in your code !

Comment: Did you put `\usepackage{tikz}` before `\begin{document}` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's good for me :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

fgfdhghgd

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0) -- (0,1) -- (1,1);
\end{tikzpicture}

ksgkgskjs
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

I didn't notice I was using `\usepackage[dvips]{graphicx}` a the same time.

Comment: Can you elaborate, just in case someone else finds this question? It's not clear to me how TikZ and graphicx would interfere with each other, they certainly can be loaded at the same time and in any order.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, as there is no adverse interaction between [`graphicx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx) and/or [`tikz`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pgf).

Comment: @wrtlprnft Yes, I saw that he is the op.  But in the given code snippet there is no package `graphicx` and the given code is not compilable.  The  given answer is useful only for the op, but other readers can not reproduce or poof if that is a answer, and why and if it is perhaps the best. So more informations are needed. That's the reason for the first comment of mine ...